# Get video frames from video camera in real time without recording

Tags: ionic-framework

Im trying to get 2 video frames per second from a real time video camera capture (without recording a video). I need to get a video frame at that rate to send it to a server to process it. (Imagine something like a QR detection)

I have use the search but no answer explains how to get a video frame from the camera in real time (without recording a video).

Any hint, plugin link, o anything would be appreciate.

Comment: 4 years later, this is still non answered. I've been trying to do that for a week. I'm deseperate lol.